# Azure function input binding: Which NuGet package for "Table" attribute?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am creating a new azure function using HttpTrigger. I want to implement an azure table storage table as input binding. Following a source code example in msdn, I am not able to figure out in which NuGet package the "Table" attribute can be found.

**Compile issue:**

The type or namespace 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Line of code, causing the issue:**

```
public static async Task<IActionResult>
         Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, 
         [Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable, 
         ILogger log)
```

The source code examples in MSDN I am refering to can be found here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table.md#input---c-example---one-

and here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---c-example---cloudtable

The second example also shows the using directives. But even when copying the example the table-attribute cannot be resolved properly.

I have also seen this stackoverflow thread:

[input-binding to table storage with an http-triggered function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465532/input-binding-to-table-storage-with-an-http-triggered-function)

but the first solution is only a workaround for me, as the table-storage connection is done during execution of the function and not as input binding. If you see the second proposed solution, it shows same code as in MSDN.

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TableStorageIntegration.HTTPTrigger
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("DoSomething")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,      
            [Table("AzureWebJobsHostLogscommon")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string someHttpGetParameter = req.Query["someParameter"];
            // .... 
            // Some addition code to be executed here but not relevant for the issue
            // .....
            return new OkObjectResult($"Data provided");
        }
    }
}
```

Is the proposed implementation still valid? And if yes, which NuGet package do I have to install to resolve the table attribute?

Comment: Try adding this NuGet Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage

Comment: Yes, that worked. Could you just send your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Tvm!

Comment: glad it helped. see below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add this NuGet Package: https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage

Comment: Warning: the support for the Table binding hasn't been carried forward in 5.0.0 of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage. Use 4.0.5 or the Table Storage SDKs. See this thread:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607702/microsoftazurewebjobsextensionsstorage-500-and-tab.html

Answer (score 6):

So seems like they have [removed `TableAttribute`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25694) for some reason.

However they are [working](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25342) on bringing it back early 2022.

In the meantime, there are a couple of workarounds if you are using Azure Tables:

- Remain on the v4 version of the Functions Extensions which has support for Tables until the new extension is released
- Directly interact with the Azure Tables service from the Azure Function code by using the Azure.Data.Tables library linked above.

Answer (score -1):

According to my test, if you want to implement "Table" attribute, you can extend the class `TableEntity`. For example

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace TestFunapp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        # install package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("People")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log, ExecutionContext  context)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<People>("Jim", "Xu");

            TableResult retrievedResult = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
                log.LogInformation(((People)retrievedResult.Result).Email);

            else
                log.LogInformation("The Email could not be retrieved.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
    public class People : TableEntity
    {

        public People(string lastName, string firstName)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = lastName;
            this.RowKey = firstName;
        }

        public People() { }

        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#input---c-example---cloudtable).

Comment: Thanks for the example. For me, the most important information is the line # install package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage which resolved the type or namespace could not be found issue. So same as @silent already mentioned in his comment.