# The type or namespace name 'Queue' could not be found in Azure Functions Http Trigger C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have created Azure Functions Http Trigger (C#) through VS Code.

I'm getting few namespace errors which I tried to resolve by installing few packages like `Azure WebJobs`, `Azure WebJobs Extensions`, `System Component DataAnnotation` package but the error is not going.

The error is in this image - [Click on Me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnrdY.png)

**Error in Text Format:**
For this line:

```
[Queue("orders")] IAsyncCollector<Order> orderQueue,
```

**Error:**

```
The type or namespace name 'QueueAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [pluralsightfuncs]csharp(CS0246)
The type or namespace name 'Queue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [pluralsightfuncs]csharp(CS0246)
```

For this line:

```
[Table("orders")] IAsyncCollector<Order> orderTable,
```

**Error:**

```
The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [pluralsightfuncs]csharp(CS0246)
The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [pluralsightfuncs]csharp(CS0246)
```

Code is available in https://github.com/licjapodaca/pluralsightfuncs/blob/master/OnPaymentReceived.cs

**My .csproj code:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You need to use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues` package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822923/azure-function-input-binding-which-nuget-package-for-table-attribute

Comment: Thank you @Chetan, Sometimes the Storage package is working with Queue and table attribute but sometimes each attribute asks to write related packages like queues, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the workaround could be solve the above issue, I have tested in my environment with your code to remove those errors and its working fine as expected .

As suggested by @Chetan in [**`comment`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822923/azure-function-input-binding-which-nuget-package-for-table-attribute) found that,
We need to Install `Nuget package` `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5"` and it will remove the above two errors.

`.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here are the screenshots for your reference:
[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:
MS DOC: [CREATE AZURE FUNCTION USING VSCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp) & [Azure Table storage bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table)

Comment: Hello @AjayKumarGhose-MT, As I have installed `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` package already but still getting the error. As chetan suggested me to use sub-package of storage i.e., queues `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you please let me know which version you have installed `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` - v4.0.5

Comment: In my case when try to install `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues` it resolve the issue for queue attribute but getting same error in table attribute.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/0Oy8kes.png - this is my .csproj file where you can see the packages with their versions i installed

Comment: `System Component DataAnnotation` - install this for your error on table attribute

Comment: In your project, you're using azure functions core tools version 4 but i have included v3 in the question - have you seen?

Comment: Hello @KrishTechy ,Glad to know your issue got resolved. As suggested here in this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp I have created `.net6 azure function using v4` . Thank you.

Comment: Hello @AjayKumarGhose-MT, could you please tell me the package required for table attribute resolving as I have mentioned that in the question!

Comment: As per the question i have mentioned in answer that we can use this to avoid the issue that you are getting `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5"` . For more information please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822923/azure-function-input-binding-which-nuget-package-for-table-attribute